# Access a Backbone model from a collection.where

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using the method `where` on my Backbone collection like so:

`var quote = app.Collections.quotes.where({Id: parseInt(id, 10)});`

However, to access the only result/Model (as it's by ID, there's only going to be one) - how can I get the actual Model without resorting to using this:

`var onlyModel = quote[0]` ?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use `get` on the collection. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get

```
var quote = app.Collection.quotes.get(parseInt(id, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone proxies Underscore functions on collections and notably [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) that will return the first match found.

> **findWhere** _.findWhere(list, properties)
>   Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

Your query can be written as

```
var quote = app.Collections.quotes.findWhere({Id: parseInt(id, 10)});
```

But in your case, if you are indeed looking for the model with a given id, you can directly use the [get](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) method

> **get** *collection.get(id)*
>   Get a model from a collection, specified by an id, a cid, or by passing in a model.

```
 var quote = app.Collection.quotes.get(id);
```